# Spring Security 5.1.0 @Query() on findAll() with custom principal object giving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I've created an `@Filter` and included it in my filter chain in my `WebSecurityConfig` class as such

```
httpSecurity
.addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(jwtService, exceptionController), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

In my `JWTFilter` I set the `SecurityContextHolder` authorization to a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with a custom object `UserInfo` as such

```
UserInfo userInfo = this.service.getUserFromToken(token);
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userInfo, null, authorities);

authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(req));

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

I'm trying to use expression language in my `InvoiceRepository` to filter my `findAll()` by my logged in user with a query as such

```
@Query("select i from Invoice i where supplyId in ?#{ principal?.supplier.supplyId }")
Iterable<Invoice>findAll()
```

This is the error i'm receiving

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getFunctions()Ljava/util/Map;
```

I have checked using an `@Controller` to see if the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuththentication()` is getting set and it is. It's returning my `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` object with my principal attached and able to be cast to `UserInfo`.

I have included this class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring Security 5.1, requires Spring 5.1 which isn't supported on released Spring Boot versions yet (unless you are using the 2.1 milestone versions).Looks like you are mixing things you shouldn't be mixing.

Comment: this was the issue for sure. I removed all security dependencies added spring-boot-starter-security, then added spring-security-data with the correct version of 5.0.8 and it worked. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As per M. Deinum mentioned, I was mixing different versions of spring-boot and spring-security dependencies.

I removed all spring-security dependences, added latest version of `spring-boot-starter-security` to match my version of `spring-boot` and I added `spring-security-data 5.0.8.RELEASE` which matched the spring-security versions that the `spring-boot-starter-security` was implementing. `spring-security-data` auto configures the `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` without needing to create my own `SecurityConfiguration` class. With the `SecurityConfiguration` left in place, it was throwing an error that there were two `SecurityEvaluationContextExtensions`, removing the `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` from the `SecurityConfiguration` resolved this problem